# Client asking for more and more, but getting paid very little

Tags: clients

So first off, let me explain the situation I am in. A client is asking me to do more and more but being paid very little (300$, but the project is worth in the thousands because of the things I added). The client is a friend I know and this is the first web design project I am being paid for (I was asked because she knew of my coding experience).

When we met to discuss what she wanted, I accepted the task. At first I was alright with being asked if I would add this small thing and that small thing. But soon she started to ask for bigger and more complex things, this has lead me to this situation. I am confused on whether to ask for more money, or just tell her to stop. If I ask for more money, I am afraid she will be offended. Likewise if I tell her to stop.

The thing is, as I said above this is my first professional programming work I have done for anyone.

Comment: Don't ask for more money. Bill for the hours you worked on every extra features that you add. The client must expect that you will bill when they require you to perform some work, that is how business works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short answer:** It's called *scope creep*.  You should only be doing what was in your original quote/scope.

I am assuming that you did an initial quote for your client.  What was your agreed scope?  Anything beyond that is a variation and needs to be quoted for separately.

If you don't have an agreed scope, then you need to stop what you are doing immediately, and negotiate a set of functionality that you are prepared to do to meet what you originally quoted.  Then you can quote and specify *carefully* what you will do for future work.  Otherwise you are simply being taken advantage of, and will continue until you *do* tell them that you will do no more unless you are adequately compensated for your work.

Comment: And when the O.P. is `"adequately compensated for the work"`, the other person (most likely) will give up on the changes. Specially if they are really complex things (like an automatic newsletter system to send it to multiple clients' groups and each group has a different layout for the newsletter with different information and that must be sent in different times). But that is really what happens in the real world and this is the course of action that should be taken.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have document of set of agreed requirements and quote based on that? If yes then you should stop work then show that document to client that these are things which we have agreed to complete in fixed cost for ex: $300 And by this way you can ask for more payment for new requirement and additional changes.

If you have discussed all requirements verbally then stop work right now and explain to client that all things are done as per our verbally discussed requirement before start project , I really can not do additional tasks in same cost. If you will pay extra then I can continue work. And for this please create requirement document so in future same problem will not occur.

And obviously business is business , Its fine that client is your friend and you provide  minor additional work in free but it should have limit and you will have to be professional.